# What are the differences between MakeSingleTon and MakeInstance in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

MakeSingleTon:

```
void Awake()
{
    MakeSingleTon();
}


void MakeSingleTon()
{
    if(instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

MakeInstance:

```
void Awake()
{
    MakeInstance();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    instance = null;
}

void MakeInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

I just have learnt to code C# and i have no idea what are/is the difference(s) between `MakeInstance` and `MakeSingleTon`, I think they are just the same because for some of my experiments, they have the same function...

So, what are the differences between them or they are just the same?

Comment: Nothing it could be called "fred" if you wanted, its just a name, however your singleton is set to not destroy, and like highlander there can be only 1, the other can have multiples, but only 1 of them would register as the one answering to "instance" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write your "singleton" code to like this:

```
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

With the code changed to look similar to your Single Instance code, you can now see that both do effectively the same thing. The only difference is that the Singleton automatically destroys itself if there already exists another instance.

Typically, Singletons are used for logic that should only be created once and should persist throughout the life of your game. If another instance is created, it should immediately destroy itself to avoid contention. Things like "score managers" are a good example. I.E. if a scene changes and the new scene tries to create a new Score Manager, you don't want your score to reset.

**Unless you're changing scenes often and need to persist your instances across multiple scenes, I would recommend just using Single Instance and not Singleton.**

You can only call DontDestroyOnLoad on root objects in the hierarchy, so you can only add Singleton scripts on root objects. You can make any object in your hierarchy a Single Instance.